# jquery/javascript: $(document).trigger vs normal function call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-trigger

I just saw two javascript files:

first one had called following line after some success ajax call:

```
$(document).trigger("locationloaded");
```

The second js had:

```
$(document).on('locationloaded', function () {
   //few lines of code here
});
```

Bit new to JS, just curious to know, could there be any valid reason for calling locationloaded through trigger? Why can't we have simple function as locationloaded() which would be called from first js? If both do the same work, which one should be used?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Elements are propagated, and jquery is based on the dom. Thats the usecase for .trigger...

Comment: So, we should use trigger only for dom? not for scenario like above?

Comment: This is the problem when you work with anonymous functions. Since you define the method for the event without a name, you'll need to trigger the event instead of directly calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

## Event declaration

`on` registers an event; in this case the `locationloaded`. And since the `locationloaded` is a custom event and the only way to fire the event is through the `trigger` method.

### Registers an Event `customevent` and attach the function `locationloaded`

```
$(document).on('customevent', locationloaded);

function locationloaded() {
    console.log('The custom event is triggered inside the "locationlaoded" function');
}
```

### Fires the Event: `customevent`

```
$(document).trigger("customevent");
```

In turn, logs the message `The custom event is triggered inside the "locationlaoded" function`

### Using `trigger` vs calling the function directly; i.e. `locationloaded()`

Using `trigger` broadcast a message to the **DOM** that an event is fired. So any separate javascript file that listens to an event immediately notified

```
$(document).trigger('subscribe');
```

On the same file as `$(document).trigger('subscribe')`

```
$(document).on('subscribe', function() {
   // Send email
});
```

On the other javascript file

```
$(document).on('subscribe', function() {
   // Save data
});
```

Whereas calling a declared function directly only allows any other performing tasks within the same context of the method called.

That's why the `$(document).trigger('locationloaded`)` is declared in a separate file, at the same time if the event is triggered and broadcast, then, the other file can perform its tasks.

Comment: Didn't answer my question, why can't I use simple function call in above scenario?

Comment: I think you're confused by  the naming of your posted code. I updated my code to reflect the new approach. Clearly `locationloaded` parameter in your `trigger` function is the same event name declared on the `on` function. And since it is a custom event the only way to trigger is by explicitly using the `trigger` function.

Comment: Okay. What is the difference if I call $(document).trigger("customevent"); VS i call locationloaded() directly?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [jQuery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Any event handlers attached with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method.

Comment: Didn't answer my question, why can't I use simple function call in above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to following a software engineering principle of having "high cohesion and low coupling" for higher quality software.

By using events you can define *zero* to *many* handlers that can do different things for different purposes.  Don't need to do anything when locationloaded?  Great! Have three separate things that need to be done for three different purposes defined in different places? No problem! Each event handler only has to be concerned with its own job.  This is a very flexible arrangement - high cohesion.

If you just called a function, one and only one function defined in one place must exist.  This function must serve every purpose no matter if those purposes are not related.  The function must exist whether needed or not.  Very rigid higher coupling, lower cohesion arrangement.